# Scale and rotate in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, shader

Is there a way to include aspect ratio correction without using matrices in OpenGL ES?

I am writing a simple shader to rotate a texture.

```
void main()  
{  
    mat2 rotX = mat2(cosA, sinA, -sinA, cosA);  
    vec4 a_pos = a_position;
    a_pos.xy = a_position.xy * rotZ;  
    gl_Position = a_pos;  
}
```

But the problem is that the image is getting skewed when rotating.
In normal openGL, we use something like   gluPerspective(fov, (float)windowWidth/(float)windowHeight, zNear, zFar);
How do i do the same with shaders?
**Note: I'd prefer not using a matrix.**

Answer (score 2):

Include aspect ratio fix in geometry of rendered object? I did so in my font rendering tool, position of verts in each rect is corrected by aspect ratio of screen, and yes i know that its better and easier do use matrix fix but i didnt know it when i was writing this tool, and it works fine:)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually translate a code of GluPerspective to shader:
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluPerspective_code

But it is not efficient to calcuelte this matrix for each vertex. So you can manually calculate it for your device screen. Look at [these](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=251073) posts

Answer (score 0):

Just change the matrix multiplication order for rotation:

```
a_pos.xy = rotZ * a_position.xy;
```